# How to shorten this condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new with javascript. Thank-you every body.

```
if ((!Boolean(Profile["firstName"]) || !Boolean(Profile["lastName"]) || !Boolean(Profile["email"]))
      && location.pathname !== "/login" && location.pathname !== "/reset-password" && location.pathname !== "/forget-password") {    
            return  (<HomeLayout>)
 }
```

Comment: `!Boolean(Profile["firstName"])` -> `!Profile["firstName"]` no need for the boolean conversion when NOT already does it when inverting.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly you don't need those booleans and also you can use an array to check those path names.

```js
const allowedLocations = ["/forget-password","/login","/reset-password"]
if ((!Profile.firstName || !Profile.lastName || !Profile.email) && !allowedLocations.includes(locatioh.pathName)) {
  return ( < HomeLayout > )
}
```

it might be overkill but you can also try something like this:

```
const requiredProps = ["firstName", "lastName", "email"]

if( requiredProps.some(r=> !Profile[r])  ...)
```

As @dcangulo mentioned in the comments you can use object destructuring to make it neater:

```
const { firstName, lastName, email } = Profile 
if( (!firstName || !lastName || !email) ...)
```

Comment: Maybe `const { firstName, lastName, email } = Profile` then `!firstName || !lastName || !email`.

Comment: Removing the new line before the return statement was a touch of genius :)

Answer (score 2):

I would define those field names and locations first. It's a good coding practice anyway. Then it becomes simpler to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish:

```
const field_names = ["firstName", "lastName", "email"];
const locations = ["/forget-password", "/login", "/reset-password"];

if(field_names.find(i => !Profile[i]) || !locations.includes(location.pathName)){
  return  (<HomeLayout>)
}
```

Or here is a runnable code:

```js
const field_names = ["firstName", "lastName", "email"];
const locations = ["/forget-password", "/login", "/reset-password"];

const Profile = {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Done', email: ''}
const pathName = '/login'

if(field_names.find(i => !Profile[i]) || !locations.includes(pathName)){
  console.log('Executing...')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than focus on making it shorter, how about making it clearer?

```
const allowedLocations = ["/forget-password", "/login", "/reset-password"];
const missingProfileDetail = !Profile.firstName ||
                             !Profile.lastName ||
                             !Profile.email;
if (missingProfileDetail && !allowedLocations.includes(locatioh.pathName)) {
  return ( < HomeLayout > )
}
```

Note that *if* you can move `missingProfileDetail` into `Profile.isMissingDetail()`, that's the way, and it makes it **shorter, clearer and reusable**.

```
if (Profile.isMissingDetail() && !allowedLocations.includes(locatioh.pathName))
// ...
```

Thank you @Eldar, I used your answer as a template (: - hope you don't mind.

Comment: maybe `isMissingLoginEssential`? hard to give a good name without context.